# Can't strip object in column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with column 'surface-area':

```
|surface-area|

    51 m²
```

I want to strip the m² part:

```
df['surface-area'] = df['surface-area'].apply(lambda x: str(x.rstrip(' m²')))
```

Which results in this error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

Comment: convert into string and then use the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem are `NaN`s values, so use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['surface-area'] = df['surface-area'].str.rstrip(' m²')
```